# How many resources will a default Ubuntu LTS server install require?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, provisioning

Given a default (no extra packages installed) instance of Ubuntu Server LTS, how many resources are needed?

I'm curious about:

```
* CPU consumption
* RAM working set
* Network needed
* Disk I/O
* Storage space needed
```

Information on marginal increase per user is also welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Out of the box the [Absolute minimum requirements](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements#Absolute%20minimum%20installation) are:

- Intel 486 processor
- 32 MB of system memory (RAM)
- 300 MB of disk space

Since an out of the box install does pretty much nothing, those specs should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

The Ubuntu Server 8.04 [install guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/8.04/serverguide/C/preparing-to-install.html) suggests a minimum of 384MB of RAM to install, and 500MB of disk space.

Based on my [Linode](http://www.linode.com/?r=a4260271d3642eed634a2204375f256d79149b89) image, the following is reasonably close to minimal:

Syslog runs every 20 minutes to write a --MARK--, incurring a small amount of disk activity and storage use. Any logging activity will generally be stored in /var/log/messages.

Cron runs hourly, daily, weekly and monthly; daily events include apt-get'ting new updates (but not installing them).

Answer (score 1):

I don't see how answers to these questions is going to help you at all.

CPU usage of a new install?  Under 1% even on slow systems.

Resource per user account?  Very close to zero.  Each user gets a homedir with three files:

```
 220 bytes .bash_logout 
3115 bytes .bashrc
 675 bytes .profile
```

The exact space requirements for the homedir will depend on the block size of your disk.  On my system it's about 16kb.

Answer (score 0):

Far too little information. Without knowing what the server is doing (is it hosting static content via nginx? PHP via Apache? converting AVIs to FLV with ffmpeg? OpenArena game server?) it's impossible to give any sort of meaningful answer.

Comment: None of those; the question is what it wants out of the box. Obviously per user won't quite make sense without a use, but they need homedirs, etc.